# Join two count() query into single output query

Tags: mysql

I have a two queries

```
select date(o.createddate),count(*) 
from table1 o,table2 p 
where p.col1=o.col1 
    and o.createddate>='2021-02-10 00:00:00' 
    and p.col2=true 
group by date(o.createddate);

select date(o.createddate),count(*) 
from table1 o,table2 p 
where p.col1=o.col1 
    and o.createddate>='2021-02-10 00:00:00' 
group by date(o.createddate);
```

I want two queries result into single query output like below

```
select date(o.createddate),cnt1,cnt2
```

How i can get the result

Comment: Please edit your question and format your queries as code using the `{}` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with `CASE`:

```
select date(o.createddate)
    ,count(*) as cnt1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN p.col2=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS cnt2
from table1 o,table2 p 
where p.col1=o.col1 
    and o.createddate>='2021-02-10 00:00:00' 
group by date(o.createddate);
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working as expected result.

Comment: @ManigandanM just to let you know, there is an "accept" button below the answer's score. It also earns you 2 points.